# How to Write assets URL on Javascript Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel

heres my code `'<img src="'{{asset('/images/original/'+value.filename+')}}'">'+`

and I got the errors `syntax error, unexpected ')'`

I've no idea to fix this, please help.

Comment: `value.filename` is a JavaScript variable, but `asset()` is a Laravel (PHP) function. They execute at different times, so you can't directly use `value.filename` in the `asset()` function. You can do an AJAX request to get the `src` value using the filename, but your current approach will not work. Also, `{{ }}` syntax won't work in a `.js` file, so make sure this is a `<script>` within a `.blade.php` file.

Comment: if i write only the path  `'<img src="'{{asset('/images/inventory/original/')}}'">'+` that's not showing the errors, but if I add the value.filename, the error appears. 
mean the `{{ }}` tag works right?

Comment: Yup! The `{{ }}` tags are working, but you just can't use `value.filename` inside of the `asset()` method, since it's a JavaScript variable.

Comment: solved,
i write like this 
`<img src="{{asset("/images/inventory/original")}}'+'/'+value.filenames+'">'+`
Thanks.

Comment: Nice; using the JS variable after the PHP call should work perfectly fine for this situation. Good stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, Write the url like this.

`'<img src="{{asset("/images/inventory/original")}}'+'/'+value.filenames+'">'+`